# Web Api: How do I allow only my mobile app and website to connect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am building a cordova hybrid app that connects to a ASP.NET Web Api backend. I want to ensure that all requests to the backend are from my mobile app only (trusted source) and reject all other connections from other clients. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please read [ask] and share your research. There are _many_ questions and online resources discussing this subject, I've linked one of them. Note that this kind of protection often is susceptible to replay attacks, as any malicious user can just act like a legitimate user and reverse engineer your app or client code on the website.